# Running TestNG testng.xml tests from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, classpath, testng

I have some packages

```
com.company.testing.module1
com.company.testing.module2
com.company.testing.module3
```

I also have some classes that have TestNG annotations in

```
com.company.testing.tests
```

Now I put testng.xml in

```
com.company.testing
```

The XML file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Foo">
    <test name="Bar">
        <package>
            <package name="com.company.testing.tests" />
        </package>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How do I run the suite from Eclipse? What Run Configuration should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the [TestNG plug-in](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) and when you're done, you can just right click on your XML file and "Run as/Debug as... TestNG.

Comment: I didn't realize the XML can be run directly. I ran it and got `Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0` result. Seems like no test was executed. I suspect there is some classpath config that needs to be done. Am I correct? P.S. I am so surprised that the author of TestNG is answering me!

Comment: I get the same problem, 0 tests run.  I am trying to run the same setup from the DOS command prompt in Windows 7.  Did anybody figure this out?

Comment: use this in your testng.xml and replace the values as per your tests

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="testng1" verbose="1" > 
  <test name="alltests">
     <packages>
      <package name="com.sk176h.testng.simple"></package>
     </packages>
  </test>
</suite>

Comment: worked for me like a charm! but as I'm taking as a base maven test project, I've just added appropriate dependecy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the testng plugin.  Then its just a matter of running the testng task.  See the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

To run your test through `testNG.xml`
goto the class file right click and select Run as >>`run configuratins`.
Select `Suite` and browse your `testNG.xml` (default in eclipse - testng-customsuite.xml) and RUN.